# duplicated() doesn't work on Power BI

Tags: r, duplicates, powerbi

I have about 1500 rows of data I want to extract only those with repeating IDs so I used the code below but it doesn't work. I'm using R on a Power BI dash. I tried it with a simple dataset with about 10 rows, and it worked perfectly fine. What could be wrong here?

```
duplicates <- df[duplicated(df$id),]
```

Example

```
x <- c(500100:501000)
y <- c(500921,500922,500923,500924)
test <- c(x,y)
```

So you will have to be able to extract the numbers in y because those are the duplicates. When I try it on power bi, it simply returns the entire dataset.

Comment: What is happening? Don't you get the right results, or not any at all?
Could you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: It simply returns the entire dataset, nothing changed. Let me edit the question for an example.